# Rails 5: Preventing access to /admin pages based on IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been building a rails 5.2 app, and so far I want to separate or restrict access to `/admin` pages to only be accessible through office computers (local ips).

How can I achieve that, knowing I used `activeadmin` and `petergate` for authorization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `before_action` like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :filter_ip_address

  protected

  def filter_ip_address
    current_ip_address = request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
    head :unauthorized unless current_ip_address == "XX.XX.XX.XX"
  end
end
```

The example given is for `application_controller`, but you can put it wherever you need if you don't want to call it everywhere.

This is a modified version of the example I found here: https://coderwall.com/p/v980ha/restrict-ip-access-in-rails